# Forcing creation of all transformations for all assets

Tags: craft3, assets, image-transforms

Regarding a similar question I only found the advice to delete a table in the database but because I don't like fiddling with the db very much I like to ask: Are there ways to force craft to generate all transformations for all assets/images?

There is such a function in ExpressionEngine in the CP and I try to replicate this behaviour. I also installed the ImageOptimize plugin for that reason but no luck with that also.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Author of the ImageOptimize plugin... when you say no luck with that either, what is going wrong? Once you install ImageOptimize, and add an Optimized Images field type to your asset volumes, it will create all of those responsive image transform for you.

Check out the [Using the Optimized Images Field](https://nystudio107.com/docs/image-optimize/Using.html#using-the-optimized-images-field) section of the documentation.

It can't just create all of your image transforms for you, because unlike EE, you can create transforms via your frontend Twig templates as well, and there's no real way it can know what is being created there, or all of the possible permutations.

Comment: I come from many years of development with ee. One thing I don't like about EE is the dependence on plugins, because the endless cycle of updates annoys: If there is an update you want to use, the plugin is not (yet) compatible and if there is an update for the plugin, it causes problems with the CMS every second time. Therefore I want to do as much as possible without using plugins in Craft, even if there are excellent and many plugins. I bought ImageOptimize because I thought it would work with the native transformations, but you have to use the ImageOptimize fields, right?

Comment: Nope, ImageOptimize works 100% with native fields. It was specifically written such that you could uninstall it without having any ill effects on your content. The OptimizedImages field you add to an asset volume just tells it what transforms should be made. You still use regular old Asset fields.

Comment: ok, I see I understood the plugin's description completely wrong. I'm going through the documentation and see if I can use it the way we need it. thanks for your help!

Comment: I have some more questions regarding using ImageOptimize… shall I ask them here or in your github?

Comment: Either is fine with me

Comment: sorry for the break… corona brought some chaos in our business as well. how can I use ImageOptimize ONLY to generate all the already configured native transformations? and will ImageOptimize use image optimizing for that?

Comment: That's not possible to do, because nothing can predict what transforms you're actually using. ImageOptimize can only know about and pre-generate the transforms that you. make using its Optimized Images field type.